# Best way to add rel="noopener noreferrer nofollow" to all external links with vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

### Problem

I am using Django to render html templates that contain `<a>` tags. I want to add `rel="noopener noreferrer nofollow"` to all external links. Now one way is to do this manually on all templates or introduce a custom tag that contains the logic which checks the url and appends the attribute to the anchor tag. The problem comes when we display dynamically generated url links that can also be external. To cover all links, there are ways to add this attributes on client side.

### Solution 1

I have tried to get all anchor DOM elements and check if the `href` is internal or external. If external, add the `rel` attributes.

```
function setRelAttribute() {
    var elems = document.body.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        var elem = elems[i]
        var re = /mydomain.com/
        var isInternal = re.test(elem.href)
        if (!isInternal) {
            elem.rel= 'noopener noreferrer nofollow'
        }
    }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    setRelAttribute()
}, false);
```

This will execute in the beginning but it will only affect the pre-rendered anchor tags.

### Solution 2

Another option is to create a global event listener, that listens for clicks and then we check what kind of element was clicked.

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    var t = event.target;
    if (t.nodeName !== 'A') {
        return
    }
    ...
})
```

Are there any cons to both methods?

Answer (score 4):

You might be better of just writing a simple selection query like this:

```
const anchors = document.querySelectorAll( 'a[href^="http"]:not([href*="example.com"])' )
```

This will select all the `a` elements that begin with `http` (so not to select relative path locally) and don't contain `example.com`. Then simple apply it to all:

```
anchors.forEach(anchor => anchor.setAttribute( 'rel', 'noopener noreferrer nofollow'));
```

Your first method still selects local paths (like `/images/`), but those aren't going to an external site. Your second method will get confusing, as there is no easy way to know that this method is handling a click. I find it easy to be confused if your event listeners for clicks on elements are attached to the document. The browsers is already doing that work calculating where and what got clicked, so make use of it!

You can wrap the whole thing in a `DOMContentLoaded` or `pageshow` event, of course:

```
document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', event => {

    document.querySelectorAll( 'a[href^="http"]:not([href*="example.com"])' ).forEach(anchor => anchor.setAttribute( 'rel', 'noopener noreferrer nofollow' )); 

});
```

```js
document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', event => {
    
  document.querySelectorAll( 'a[href^="http"]:not([href*="example.com"])' ).forEach(anchor => { 
  
      anchor.setAttribute( 'rel', 'noopener noreferrer nofollow' );
      
  });

});
```

```css
a { padding: 20px; }
a[rel]:after { content: ' (has [rel] attribute)'}
```

```html
<a href="https://google.com/query">External</a>
<a href="/">Internal</a>
<a href="http://example.com/query">My Domain</a>
```

Comment: This is quite practical, but the problem is with the dynamic content. Your solution is only executed in the beginning on DOMContentLoaded.

Comment: Ah yes. If you want dynamic, a mutationobserver can do the trick. Will amend post when i can.